# Application level floating views with navigation in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog, android-windowmanager

I have to show a floating button that will be added in WindowManager so it remain on the top of all Activities. (I have done this part using https://github.com/marshallino16/FloatingView)

When that button is tapped I have to open screen and show detail view and navigate between other views. To achieve this thing I can do following things either adding

1 - PopUpWindow

2 - Dialog

But I cannot provide navigation using either of them. So my questions is.

- What is the best way to add multiple views and providing navigation between them while keeping everything above the application that is running it.
- How can we add Activity so that it won't pause user application?

Answer (score 0):

You should open Activity and implement all navigation inside it.

Android may pause activities behind, so make your Activity only for part of the screen.

Inside Activity hide floating button and show it again on exit.

Comment: Yes for now I am adding activity on top of user activity and using default navigation provided by android. The only reason I wanted to this was that I dont want to pause users Activity while adding my view. Secondly I just wanted to know if there is any way like in iOS that you can get window of application. But it seems that there is window of activity or global window of system.